# Bash script to copy source catalog to two destination catalogs, verify and delete source if successful

Tags: macos, bash, rsync, nfs

OS: OSX mountain lion

I am trying to write a script that does the following

- Check if file1  exist on destination 1 (bitcasa)
  if exist then copy source folder to destination 1
  if file does not exist find bitcasa process and kill it then wait 60sec then start bicasa.
     try again (loop?) #bitcasa sometimes stops working and have to be restarted.
- Check if file2 exist on destination 2 (nfs share) 
  if exist then copy source folder to destination 1
  if file does not exist try to mount nfs share.
    try again (loop?)
- verify copied files
  if files copied successfully delete source files
- I only want the script to try a few times, if it ant ping the nas host it should give up and try the next time the script runs. I want to run the script every 2h. crontab seam to have been removed in mountain lion.

When I write this down I realize it is a bit more complicated than I first thought.

First regarding mount a nfs share, in OsX if you eject a mounted nfs share the folder in /Volumes gets removed. What is the best way to make sure a nfs share i always mounted if the nas is available? This might be handled outside the script?
If i manually mount the nfs share I will need to create /Volumes/media and this will result in that if I use the gui to mount the share will use /Volumes/media-1/ sins /Volumes/media vill already exist.

Regarding killing a process by name sins I cant know the PID, I tried with linux command i found:
    kill `ps -ef | grep bitcasa | grep -v grep | awk ‘{print $2}’` this did not work.

I have no idea how to check if all files were successfully copied, maybe rsync can take care of this?

I have started with this (not tested)

```
    #check if bitcasa is running (if file exist)
    if [ -f /Volumes/Bitcasa\ Infinite\ Drive/file.ext ]
    then
    rsync -avz /Users/username/source /Volumes/Bitcasa\ Infinite\ Drive/destination/
       else
       #Bitcasa might have stopped, check if process i running, kill if it is, then start bitcasa
    fi
    #Check if nfs share is mounted (if file exist)
    if [ -f /Volumes/media/file.ext ]
    then
    rsync -avz /Users/username/source /Volumes/media/
    fi
        else
        #nfs share (192.168.1.106:/media/) need to be mounted to /Volumes/media
```

I will do some more work on it myself but I know I will need help.

Or am I doing this way to complicated? maybe a backup program can do this?

Answer (score 1):

For your `kill ... ps` problem, you can use [`killall`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/killall.1.html), which kills all processes having a given name

```
killall bitcasa
```

or see [`man ps`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ps.1.html) and use a user defined format, which simplifies the selection

```
ps -o pid,comm | awk '/bitcasa/ { print $1; }' | xargs kill
```

For the nas, if you can log into it and install rsync and ssh (or have it already installed), you don't need to mount anything. You can just give `192.168.1.106:/media/` as the destination to rsync and rsync will do everything necessary.

In any case, first check and mount if necessary and then start rsync when everything is set up properly not the other way round

```
if [ ! -f "/Volumes/Bitcasa Infinite Drive/file.ext" ]; then
    # kill bitcasa, restart bitcasa
fi

rsync -avz /Users/username/source "/Volumes/Bitcasa Infinite Drive/destination/"
```

same for nas

```
if [ ! -f "/Volumes/media/file.ext" ]; then
    # mount nas nfs share
fi

rsync -avz /Users/username/source "/Volumes/media/"
```

or if you have rsync and ssh on your nas, just

```
rsync -avz /Users/username/source 192.168.1.106:/media/
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course I should just rsync to my nas and not care if it is mounted or not. Will keep working on the script later today.